# why is xml not displayed when I format is as code?

Tags: support, markdown

I copied some xml to an answer, and I formatted it as code, but it hides everything between the `<` and `>` braces.

Answer is [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90169/sql-server-import-export-cannot-copy-geo-columns/90177#90177).

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [status-bydesign](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) issue because the code is being placed after a bullet list.

There is a [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item) that deals with how to bypass the issue.

There are several ways to work around it, but I updated the answer to use 8 spaces instead of the standard 4 spaces for code and it now is displaying properly.

Comment: Thank you very much